# Got an updateTotal() not defined error. updateTotal() Function seems to be defined and called appropriately. Why would I be getting this error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

updateTotal() function not defined, however, i have the function defined inside of $(document).ready( function () { and have called updateTotal() inside of other methods where it needs to be used. Running total not updating. console is showing an updateTotal() not defined.
Why could i be getting this error?

```
$(document).ready( function () {

 $('#plan').on('change', function() {
   var priceText;

   switch(this.value) {
     case 'monthly':
      priceText = '10.00 /mo';
      break;
     case 'quarterly':
      priceText = '$9.00 /mo';
      break;
     case 'yearly':
      priceText = '7.00 /mo';
      break;
   }

   $('#price').text(priceText)
  });

 function updateTotal() {
  var total = 0;

  var entries = $('.entry')

  if (entries.length)
    $('#empty').show();
  else
    $('#empty').hide();

  $('.entry').each( function(index, entry) {
    var data = $(entry).data();
    var price = parseFloat(data.price)
    var installment = data.plan
    switch(installment) {
      case 'monthly':
        total += price;
        break;
      case 'quarterly':
        total += price * 4;
        break;
      case 'yearly':
        total += price * 12;
        break;
    }
  })

  $('#total').text('$' + total);
}
});


$('#add').on('click', function() {
  var plan = $('#plan')
  var installment = plan.val();
  var price = $('#price').text();
  var inCart = $('#in_cart');
  var numeric = price.replace(/[[A-Za-z$\/\s]/g, '');
  var data = 'data-price="' + numeric + '" data-plan="' + 
  installment + '"';
  inCart.append('<li>' + installment + ' - ' + price + '<button 
 class="remove">X</button></li>')
  updateTotal();
});

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parents('li').remove();
  $('#empty').on('click', function() {
    $('#in_cart').empty();
    updateTotal();
  });
```

});

Comment: Suggested Duplicate: [What is the scope of variables in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are scoped in global or function scope, so `updateTotal` is visible only in `document.ready` function.

You should try to define `updateTotal` in global scope (outside document.ready) or create some common scope using IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to not to populate global scope too much.

Some info about scoping:
https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Comment: thanks! error went away after defining function outside of document.ready

Comment: After debugging, I discovered the function did in fact need to be inside document.ready. The inCart.append line was not written properly. Needed an <li class> and also needed to append price.